# How to display all callback results (formatted) at once

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs, callback

I have a callback that sends data once they are ready (e.g., an array of 5 names after I do a left-click). I want to display all the sent data to an Ext.Panel, but it gets only displayed in the Ext.Panel the last object of the array (e.g., array goes from 1 to 5, and 1 to 4 appears really quick and in the end only 5 remains). Besides, I want to display these data by rows, and not like an array. How can I achieve that?

Code:

```
  trigger: function(e) {
    /* define some here */
    /*...*/
    $.ajax({
      /*...*/
      success: function(result){
        /*...*/
        var temp1 = 'name1';
        callback(temp1);
      }
    });
    $.ajax({
      /*...*/
      success: function(result){
        /*...*/
        var temp2 = 'name2';
        callback(temp2);
      }
    });
function callback(result){
    console.log('all results but they appear one by one here like: ' + result);

        var store = new Ext.Panel({
            html: result,
            border: false,
            bodyStyle: {
                'padding': '6px'
            },
            autoHeight: true
        });
};
```

Comment: Is "var.add(store);" right?

Comment: What version of extJS are you using?

Comment: thanks your replies. adrield: it's right, this store is added to another component, it is just not shown here. sjm: I'm using extjs 3.4.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what you get ?

Comment: I added some more info to try to explain the behaviour I get, I will try to do a working example in jsfiddle. Basically, I do left-click to trigger an event, and all I get from two ajax calls should go to the html in the Ext.Panel, but so far they appear one by one, I need all of them after all ajax results arrive. I think I get one by one because of the ajax output itself. I was thinking to adapt a timer or an Ext.Store in the Ext.Panel to "wait" and "receive" all results once all of them are ready to be used, but Ext.Store is not allowed inside an Ext.Panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know hom many ajax requests you do (5), I suggest you to create a global variable wich will memorize the result of all your callback and insert into your panel once they are all loaded :

```
var myData = [];    

function callback(result){
    myData.push(result);
    if (myData.length == 5) {
          var store = new Ext.Panel({
              html: myDataFormated , // Here add some style by transforming myData array
              border: false,
              bodyStyle: {
                 'padding': '6px'
              },
              autoHeight: true
          });   
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick reply, I'm at work right now and away form my pc at home, so can't test your suggestions. However, this thing is that `result` can bring an array with either 1 or 10 elements, it depends on how many layers have been loaded. How could I define that? I mean, depending on the number of elements in the end stored in the array?

Comment: Perhaps add a paramter to your callback function with result.length and replace 5 by that variable  ?

Comment: but the problem is that I'd need to know in the first place the number of elements of the array/variable, because `result` will send every variable to the array, so it gets displayed. I'd need to wait until `myData` is first "filled", afterwards it should be displayed. I think it'd be that way, but how can I wait until is filled? how can I define that?

Comment: I thought you were passing "temp1...5" to thé callback. ? But you send the whole array?

Comment: the idea is to send the whole array at once, then display it in the panel. But I noticed that `callback(result)` fills in one by one, so every element of the array gets displayed one by one. I recently tried `setTimeout` and it seems to work, the problem is that I need to set a specific time period and sometimes the last callback lasts a bit longer than "normal". It'd be great if I just could catch all elements from the callback at once, though.

Comment: In my answer, it will only shows if all data I received no ?

Comment: yeap, but in my case, I sometimes click on 3 layers, sometimes on 5, sometimes on 8 and so forth, so I can't add a specific number, that's the issue.

Comment: Inside the trigger function, you can t know thé number of items you clicked?